# How to use updateselection () in. Rhiny corectly

Tags: shiny, updates, shiny-server, auto-update

I have an issue on my script in **RShiny**. In fact the script works, but I have this error/warning :

> Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1): x, fill

You can access my script on  [github] (https://github.com/vladamihaesei/Rshiny_stripes_temperatures)

Answer (score 0):

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(RColorBrewer)

temp <- read.csv("Temperature_1961-2010.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
col_strip <- brewer.pal(11, "RdBu")

ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("darkly"),
                titlePanel("Temperature of Romania 1961-2010"),
                sidebarLayout(
                  sidebarPanel(
                    selectInput("RegiuneInput", "Regiune",
                                choices = unique(temp$CMR)),
                    selectInput("judetInput", "Judet",
                                choices = unique(temp$NUME))
                  ),
                  mainPanel(plotOutput("coolplot"))
                )
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$RegiuneInput,
               updateSelectInput(session, "judetInput", "Judet",
                                 choices = unique(temp$NUME[temp$CMR==input$RegiuneInput])))

  output$coolplot <- renderPlot({
    filtered1 <- temp  %>%
      filter(CMR == isolate(input$RegiuneInput),
             NUME == input$judetInput)

    ggplot(filtered1,
           aes(x = Data, y = 1, fill = Temp))+
      geom_tile() +
      scale_fill_gradientn(colors = rev(col_strip)) +
      guides(fill = guide_colorbar(barwidth = 1)) +
      theme_void()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```